# How to integrate dropdown menu on nav header

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have this structure :

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="nav-left">My Title/div>
  <div class="nav-right">
    <ul>
      <li class="icons">
        <a title="Lang" id="langtoggle" class="fas fa-language"></a>
        <a title="Theme" id="themetoggle" class="fas fa-moon" onclick="switchTheme()"></a>
        <a id="toggle-nav" onclick="toggleNav()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And I found a great drop down menu :

```html
<li class="language-switcher">
  <details class="dropdown">
    <summary role="button" aria-haspopup="true" title="Language selection" aria-label="Language selection">
      <div class="language-switcher-icon"></div>
    </summary>
    <div class="dropdown-content" role="menu">English</div>
  </details>
</li>
```

When I try to integrate it, it takes the right position and I can't find how to my a link to use this bloc of code. The objectif is to have a lang selector that redirect to /es/ when I select Spanish for example (this part I already find how to do with this dropdown menu).

I try to remove `<li>` and `</li>` and it goes on top.
I try to replace `<details>` to `<a>` and dropdown menu don't work, it shows lang directly.
I try to simplify with :

```html
<a class="dropdown>
  <div class="dropdown-content>
    […]
```

unsuccessfully it doesn't do the job.

How can I integrate it?